# Spring 4.2.4. Autowiring list of extended generic interfaces

Tags: java, spring

```
@Autowired
private List<WalletService<Wallet>> walletServices; //Doesn't work

@Autowired
private List<WalletService> walletServices; //Everything is fine
```

Assume we have:

```
interface A<T extends W>;
interface B extends A<W1>;
interface C extends A<W2> ;
class W1 extends W;
class W2 extends W;
```

I know it is possible to inject a list of A or specific A. Can I inject a list of A to avoid an explicit cast from `List<A> to List<A<W>>`?
Now, when I try some i get org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

I think this feature is necessary to implementation a hierarchy of classes like this:

```
interface WalletService<T exends Wallet>
interface TradeWalletService extends WalletService<TradeWallet>
interface PersonalWalletService extends WalletService<PersonalWallet>
```

Maybe I'm missing something. 
Thanks in advance for your reply!

Comment: what is your spring version ?

Comment: Spring 4.2.4 version.

Comment: @DmRomantsov could you ever solve this? I am facing a similar issue and unable to autowire using any syntax

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The root cause comes from the generics definition in Java, so that `WalletService<TradeWallet>` **is not** a subclass of `WalletService<Wallet>,` therefore Spring cannot match the beans.
On of the solutions could be using upper bounded wildcards:

```
private List<WalletService<? extends Wallet>> walletServices;
```

There is also an alternative, which is error-prone and has side effects. If you annotate your `WalletService` so that Spring creates a proxy object for it,  both `WalletService<TradeWallet>` and `WalletService<PersonalWallet>` will be wrapped into proxy objects and for the outer world both look like `WalletService` w/o any generics information. This causes problems as soon as you want to inject, say, `WalletService<TradeWallet>` and Spring will fail as both proxied object match this bean definition.